# Undefined variable: id

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, select, multiple

**Contextualização**

É necessário que o usuário cadastre novas localidades no projeto através da caixa de seleção múltipla. Como serão várias localidades eu não sei como o ajax e o php processam estes dados. 

A imagem a seguir apresenta o **modal de Localidades** com a caixa de seleção múltipla. Os dados da esquerda estão todas as localidades cadastradas e a do lado direito estão as localidades selecionadas pelo usuário (serão as novas localidades cadastradas). Ao pressionar no **botão salvar** os dados à direita serão salvos no banco de dados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Erro:**

Ao editar um projeto aparece o seguinte erro:

> "Undefined variable:id"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Dúvida:**

Como pegar os dados das novas localidades salvas do projeto e exibir na caixa de seleção múltipla (no lado direito)?

**Códigos:**

**Página Html: edita.blade.php - modal com a caixa de seleção múltipla de Localidades**

```
  <!--Inicio do modal de Localidades--> 
  <div class="modal fade modal-default" id="modalLocalidade" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="examplePositionCenter"
                 role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-center">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                            </button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Localidades</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">

                            <div class="form-group col-md-18" style="display:flex">

                                <select multiple  class="esq  col-md-6" name="localidadesAtivas" required>
                                    @foreach($localidadesAtivas as $localidadeAtiva)
                                    <option value="{{$localidadeAtiva->id}}" {{$localidadeAtiva->id == $projeto->localidade_id ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{$localidadeAtiva->localidade}}</option>
                                    @endforeach   
                                </select>          

                                <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:column">
                                    <button class="dir">▶</button>
                                    <button class="esq">◀</button>
                                </div>

                                <select multiple class="dir col-md-6" name="localidadesAtivasSelects">
                                @foreach($localidadesProjeto as $localidadeProjeto)
                                <option value="{{$localidadeProjeto->id}}" {{$localidadeProjeto->id == $projeto->localidade_id ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{$localidadeProjeto->localidade}}</option>

                                @endforeach  
                                </select>
                           </div>

                        </div><!--Fim do modal-body-->

                        <div class="modal-footer">
                        <center>
                            <a id="btnSalvar" type="button" class="btn btn-primary cadNovaLocalidade" data-dismiss="modal"  align="center" style="width: 300px; height: 40px">Salvar</a>
                        </center>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
  <!--Fim do modal de Localidades-->
```

**Controlador ProjetoController.php: método edita($id, Request $request)**

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use App\Helpers\helpers;
use App\Models\Projeto;
use App\Models\Setor;
use App\Models\Proponente;
use App\Models\TipoProjeto;
use App\Models\Localidade;
use App\Models\ModalidadeApoio;
use App\Models\LocalidadeProjeto;




class ProjetoController extends Controller
{
    private $projeto;
    private $novoProjeto; 
    public  $flagStatusDoc;  //$autorizaDoc é uma flag que por default é false, se torna verdadeira quando a documentação é aprovada
    public $flagAprovacao; //$flagAprovacao é uma flag que por default é false, se torna verdadeira quando o projeto é aprovado


    //Construtor do projeto
    public function __construct(Projeto $projeto)
     {
         $this->projeto = $projeto;  
         $this->flagStatusDoc = false;  
         $this->flagAprovacao = false;
     }

     //Redireciona os dados do projeto para a página principal
     public function index(Request $request)
     {
         $permissao = verificarPermissao('Projetos');
         $projetos = Projeto::all();
         return view('admin.projeto.index',['projetos' => $projetos, 'permissoesPerfil' => $permissao]); 
     }

    //Este método apresenta o formulário para cadastrar um novo projeto
    public function novo()
    {
        $this->flagStatusDoc = false;
        $this->flagAprovacao = false;

        $setores = Setor::all();
        $proponentes = Proponente::all(); 
        $tipoProjetos = TipoProjeto::all(); 
        $modalidadeApoios = ModalidadeApoio::all();
        $localidades = Localidade::all(); 
        $permissoesAprovacao = verificarPermissao('Aprovação');
        $permissoesJuridico = verificarPermissao('Juridico');
        $permissoesGestaoContrato = verificarPermissao('Gestão Contratos e Convênios');
        $permissoesFinanceiro = verificarPermissao('Financeiro');
        $permissoesOcorrencia = verificarPermissao('Ocorrência'); 
        $permissoesAbas= verificarPermissao('Abas do Projeto'); 
        $permissoesDadosGeraisProj= verificarPermissao('Dados Gerais do Projeto'); 

        return view('admin.projeto.novo',
        ['permissoesAprovacao' =>  $permissoesAprovacao, 'permissoesJuridico' => $permissoesJuridico,
        'permissoesGestaoContrato' =>  $permissoesGestaoContrato , 'permissoesFinanceiro' => $permissoesFinanceiro,
        'permissoesOcorrencia'=> $permissoesOcorrencia, 'permissoesDadosGeraisProj' => $permissoesDadosGeraisProj,
        'permissoesAbas' =>  $permissoesAbas, 'setores' => $setores, 'proponentes' => $proponentes, 
        'tipoProjetos' => $tipoProjetos,'localidades' => $localidades,'modalidadeApoios' => $modalidadeApoios, 
        'flagStatusDoc' => $this->flagStatusDoc , 'flagAprovacao' =>  $this->flagAprovacao 
        ]);
    }

     //Método para a consulta dos projetos
     public function consulta(Request $request){

        $condicoes = [];

        if($request->id != null){
            $condicoes[] = [DB::raw('upper(id)'), 'like', DB::raw('upper("%'.$request->get('id').'%")')];
        }

        if($request->nomeProjeto != null){
            $condicoes[] = [DB::raw('upper(nome_projeto)'), 'like', DB::raw('upper("%'.$request->get('nomeProjeto').'%")')];
        }

        if($request->tipoProcesso != null){
            $condicoes[] = [DB::raw('upper(tipo_processo)'), 'like', DB::raw('upper("%'.$request->get('tipoProcesso').'%")')];
        }

        if($request->dtInicio != null){
            $condicoes[] = ['dt_inicio', '=', $request->input('dtInicio')];
        }

        if($request->dtFim != null){
            $condicoes[] = ['dt_fim', '=', $request->input('dtFim')];
        }

        $request->flash(['ID','nomeProjeto', 'tipoProcesso', 'dtInicio', 'dtFim']);

        $projetos = Projeto::where($condicoes)->orderBy('nome_projeto')->get();
        //$rotas = Route::where($condicoes)->orderBy('rota')->get();
        $permissao = verificarPermissao('Projetos');

        return view('admin.projeto.index',['projetos' => $projetos, 'permissoesPerfil' => $permissao]); 
    }


      //Método para cadastrar os dados gerais do projeto 
      public function cadastro(Request $request, Projeto $projeto)
      {
        $novoProjeto =  $projeto->salvar($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('projeto.edita', $novoProjeto->id)->with('success','Sucesso ao cadastrar');;
      }



     //Método que  redireciona para a página de editar o  Projeto
     public function edita($id, Request $request)
     {  
        $localidadesProjeto = Localidade::join('localidades_projeto', function ($join) {
            $join->on('localidade.id','=','localidades_projeto.localidade_id')
            ->where('localidades_projeto.projeto_id','=', $id); })->distinct()->get(); 

        $projetoAutorizado = Projeto::findOrFail($id);
        $this->flagStatusDoc =   $projetoAutorizado->status_documentacao == 'A' ? true : false;
        $this->flagAprovacao = false;
        $usuarios = User::where('autoriza', '=', 'S')->get();
        $setores = Setor::all();
        $proponentes = Proponente::all(); 
        $tipoProjetos = TipoProjeto::all(); 
        $modalidadeApoios = ModalidadeApoio::all();
        $localidades = Localidade::all(); 
        $localidadesAtivas = Localidade::where('ativo', '=', 'S')->orderBy('localidade', 'asc')->get(); 
        $permissoesAprovacao = verificarPermissao('Aprovação');
        $permissoesJuridico = verificarPermissao('Juridico');
        $permissoesGestaoContrato = verificarPermissao('Gestão Contratos e Convênios');
        $permissoesFinanceiro = verificarPermissao('Financeiro');
        $permissoesOcorrencia = verificarPermissao('Ocorrência'); 
        $permissoesAbas= verificarPermissao('Abas do Projeto'); 
        $permissoesDadosGeraisProj= verificarPermissao('Dados Gerais do Projeto'); 
        $usuarioResponsavel = Auth::user()->name;
        $statusDocumentacao =  $projetoAutorizado->status_documentacao == 'P' ? 'Pendente' : 'Autorizado';
        $userAutorizaDoc = User::findOrFail($projetoAutorizado->usu_autoriza_doc_id); 
        $usuarioAutorizaDoc =   !empty($userAutorizaDoc) ?  $userAutorizaDoc->name : 'Nenhum' ;
        $countLocalidadesProjeto = count(LocalidadeProjeto::where('projeto_id','=',$id)->get());



        return view('admin.projeto.edita', ['projeto' => Projeto::find($id), 'permissoesAprovacao' =>  $permissoesAprovacao, 'permissoesJuridico' => $permissoesJuridico,
                'permissoesGestaoContrato' =>  $permissoesGestaoContrato , 'permissoesFinanceiro' => $permissoesFinanceiro,
                'permissoesOcorrencia'=> $permissoesOcorrencia, 'permissoesDadosGeraisProj' => $permissoesDadosGeraisProj,
                'permissoesAbas' =>  $permissoesAbas, 'setores' => $setores, 'proponentes' => $proponentes, 'tipoProjetos' => $tipoProjetos, 'usuarios' => $usuarios,
                'localidades' => $localidades,'modalidadeApoios' => $modalidadeApoios, 'usuarioResponsavel'=>$usuarioResponsavel,'statusDocumentacao'=>$statusDocumentacao,
                'usuarioAutorizaDoc'=> $usuarioAutorizaDoc,'localidadesAtivas'=> $localidadesAtivas, 'flagStatusDoc' =>$this->flagStatusDoc, 'flagAprovacao' =>  $this->flagAprovacao,
                'countLocalidadesProjeto' =>  $countLocalidadesProjeto, 'localidadesProjeto' => $localidadesProjeto]);
     }

        //Método para atualizar o Projeto
      public function atualiza(Request $request)
      {
        $projeto = Projeto::findOrFail($request->get('numProjeto'));
        $projeto->tipo_processo = $request->get('tipoProcesso');
        $projeto->processo = $request->get('numProcesso');                      
        $projeto->dt_protocolo =  $request->get('dtProtocolo');   
        $projeto->setor_origem_id = $request->get('setor');  
        $projeto->proponente_id = $request->get('proponente'); 
        $projeto->nome_projeto = $request->get('nomeProjeto');
        $projeto->dt_inicio = $request->get('dtInicio');
        $projeto->dt_fim = $request->get('dtFim');
        $projeto->dias_intercalados = $request->get('diasIntercalados'); 
        $projeto->tipo_projeto_id = $request->get('tipoProjeto'); 
        $projeto->modalidade_apoio_id = $request->get('modalidadeApoio'); 
        $projeto->localidade_id = $request->get('localidade'); 
        $projeto->valor_solicitado = $request->get('vlSolicitado');
        $projeto->arquivo_fisico = $request->get('arquivo');
        $projeto->dt_lancamento = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
        $projeto->dt_alteracao = null; 
        $projeto->usu_lancamento_id = auth()->user()->id; //recebe o id do usuário logado
        $projeto->usu_responsavel_id = auth()->user()->id; //recebe o id do usuário logado

        $response =  $projeto->alterar($projeto);  
          if($response['success'])
          {
              return redirect()
                        ->route('projeto.edita',$projeto->id) 
                        ->with('success',$response['message']);
          }else
          {
              return redirect()
                        ->back()
                        ->with('error',$response['message']); 

          }   
      }

        //Método para autorizar a documentação do Projeto
        public function autorizaDocumentacao(Request $request)
        {
            if (!$usuario = User::findOrFail($request->get('idUsuario')))
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Usuário não encontrado'], 404);

            if (!$projeto = Projeto::findOrFail($request->get('numProjeto')))
                return response()->json(['error' => 'Projeto não encontrado'], 404);

              $statusDoc =  $request->statusDoc;

            if (Hash::check($request->get('senha'), $usuario->password)){

                $projeto->status_documentacao = $statusDoc; //muda o status da documentação para "A"
                $projeto->usu_autoriza_doc_id = $usuario->id;//id do usuário que autorizou a documentação

                 // $usuarioAutorizaDocs = $usuario->name; // nome do usuário que autorizou a documentação
                $projeto->save();

                //A variável $statusDoc consulta se o status da documentação está autorizado para o usuário logado
                $statusDoc =  Projeto::where('status_documentacao','=','A','and','usu_responsavel_id','=', Auth::user()->id )->get();
                //A variável $flagStatusDoc é verdadeira se a $statusDoc não for nula caso ao contrário ela é verdadeira
                $this->flagStatusDoc =   $statusDoc !=  null ? true : false;


                return response()
                        ->json(['success' => 'Sucesso ao Autorizar Documentação'], 200); 
            } else {
                return response()
                            ->json(['error' => 'Senha Incorreta'], 422);
            } 
        }



        //Cadastra novas localidades
        public function localidadesAtivas(Request $request, Projeto $projeto)
        {
            $projeto = $projeto->find($request->numProjeto);
            if (!$projeto)
                return response()->json(['error' => 'Projeto não encontrado'], 404);

                $projeto->localidades_projeto()->attach($request->localidadesAtivasSelects);

            return response()
                        ->json([
                            'success' => 'Sucesso ao cadastrar novas localidades'
                            ]);
        }


    //Este método remove o projeto
   public function remove(Request $request)
   {
       $projeto = Projeto::find($request->id);

      if (!$projeto)
       return response()
                ->json(['error' => 'not_found'], 404);

      $response =  $projeto->deletar($projeto);  

      if($response['success'])
      {
       return response()
               ->json(['success' => $response['message']], 200);  

      }else
      {
         // Caso não delete, informa um erro inesperado
       return redirect()
                ->json(['error' => $response['message']], 500);        
      } 
   }
}
```

**Método edita($id, Request $request)**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: E o que deveria ser a variável `id` que não existe?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, a variável id existe no método a seguir, mas por algum motivo o framework laravel não reconhece               
  public function edita($id, Request $request)
     {  
        $localidadesProjeto = Localidade::join('localidades_projeto', function ($join) {
            $join->on('localidade.id','=','localidades_projeto.localidade_id')
            ->where('localidades_projeto.projeto_id','=', $id); })->distinct()->get(); (...)

Answer (score 0):

Quando vai usar uma variável externa dentro uma função callback no PHP precisa usar ela, exemplo:
$id = 123;
metodoNome(function() **use ($id)** {
    echo $id;
});

Segue o trecho do código do método edita da classe ProjetoController.php

```
 $localidadesProjeto = Localidade::join('localidades_projeto', function ($join) use ($id) {
                            $join->on('localidade.id','=','localidades_projeto.localidade_id')
                            ->where('localidades_projeto.projeto_id','=',  $id ); })->distinct()->get();
```